# Batch Script - How to handle space in folder name with forfiles

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to write one script which scan logs directory and move logs older than 10 days to other folder. Below is part of script which is throwing folowing Error .

Error :

```
ERROR: Invalid argument/option - 'logs\logs\SHARED_ArchivedLogs_20140515"'.
Type "FORFILES /?" for usage.

forfiles /s /p %LOG_LOCATION%  -m *.* /d -%NO_DAYS% -c "cmd /c move @Path %ARCHIVE_LOCATION%"
```

**Where :**

```
  ARCHIVE_LOCATION="C:\developments\IssuesLog\space logs\logs\SHARED_ArchivedLogs_20140515"
  NO_DAYS=10
  LOG_LOCATION="C:\developments\IssuesLog\space logs\logs"
```

Even I kept double quotes around ARCHIVE_LOCATION dont know what is the issue. Most likely issue with the space in path.

Can someone please help me out to fix this issue?

Comment: Try to escape spaces with `^` or use Hexadecimal replacement for spaces (0x20) : http://ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html